# How can I get the links from a web page using WWW::Mechanize and Perl

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and trying to get all the links on a website that begin with `http://`, so far the code I have written returns values that are in hex. I would like to see the actual links it is returning. I have posted my code below, any and all inputs will be greatly appreciated.

```
use strict;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my $url = "http://search.cpan.org";

$mech->get($url);

my @foundLinks = $mech->find_all_links();
print @foundLinks;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#mech-find_all_links):

> **$mech->find_all_links( ... )**
>
> Returns all the links on the current page that match the criteria. The method for specifying link criteria is the same as in "find_link()". *Each of the links returned is a WWW::Mechanize::Link object.*

To print the links, use the `url` method to [`WWW::Mechanize::Link`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Link):

```
my @foundLinks = $mech->find_all_links();
print $_->url for @foundLinks;
```

Answer (score 3):

The return value from find_all_links is a WWW::Mechanize::Link object, so you could do like

```
 print map {$_->url} @foundlinks;
```